# Email signature distorted in react-native-render-html

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-render-html

I'm working on app which has feature to send/receive emails (mini gmail) in it. The problem is with rendering email signature. Everything else seems to work fine but when email has signature in it then this does not render correctly and whole view gets distorted. Is there any way to fix this? I'm testing on iOS

```
const ImgRenderer: CustomBlockRenderer = (props) => {
    const imgProps = useIMGElementProps(props);
    return (
        <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={imgProps.style}
            source={imgProps.source}
        />
    );
};

const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

<RenderHtml
    contentWidth={width}
    source={{ html: `${body}` }}
    renderers={renderers}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the issue you're encountering? Also precise on which platform?

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph I've attached screenshot taken from ios device.